# Keep a thread running to perform a task

Tags: java, multithreading

I have written a thread class the run method of which will pick up certain submitted jobs from a database and execute them.I have started this thread in context initialized method of my session listener so that the thread starts as soon as my server is restarted.
In the run method , the first step is to pick up all tasks which are in 'Submitted' state in database and then execute them one by one.The 
I am facing an issue when I submit a new task after all the tasks are executed.Ideally my thread should pick this up but it is not.I have checked the state of the thread and it is "RUNNABLE".Once I restart me server the thread is picking up this task but other wise.

```
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    try {

        Configuration configuration = new Configuration(); 
        configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
        ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().
        applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();
        sessionFactory =  new AnnotationConfiguration().
        buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        logger.debug("sessionFactory created in HibernateSessionFactoryListener.contextInitialized() : " + sessionFactory);
        // get servletcontext
        context = sce.getServletContext();
        // start session factory
        context.setAttribute("datasource", sessionFactory);
        isSessionActive = true;

        //SubmitTaskThread t = new SubmitTaskThread();

        t.start();

}
```

Above is the code in context initialized

the code in run method :

```
     public void run(){
    //logger1.debug("in run method of thread class");

        //SubmitTask st = new SubmitTask();
        //st.runJobs();
       //TASKS THAT ARE SUBMITTED
     try {
        pendingList=getPendingList();
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

        if (pendingList.size()>0){




        boolean isObjStorage=false;
       CornicheVO runVO;
       Transfer newTransferJob;
       List<String> locations;
       JobVO jobSubmitVo;

            for (int listSize=0;listSize<pendingList.size();listSize++){
                locations = new ArrayList<String>();
                runVO=pendingList.get(listSize);
                newTransferJob=new Transfer();
                jobSubmitVo=new JobVO();
                newTransferJob.setTask_id(runVO.getTask_Id());
                locations.add(runVO.getSrcLocDesc());
                locations.add(runVO.getDstLocDesc());
                 try {
                     drivesInfo = getLocationInfo(locations);
                } catch (CornicheException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                 try {

                    for (NasDrive drive : drivesInfo) {
                        if (drive.getSrc_loc_desc().equals(
                                runVO.getSrcLocDesc())) {
                                if ("OBJSTORAGE".equals(drive.getType())) {
                                    isObjStorage = true;
                                newTransferJob.setSrc_server_type("OOSS");
                            } else {
                                newTransferJob.setSrc_server_type("NAS");
                            }
                            newTransferJob.setSrc_server(drive.getSrc_server());
                            newTransferJob.setSrc_server_dflt_loc(drive.getSrc_Loc());
                            newTransferJob.setSrc_server_id(drive.getUsr_id());
                            newTransferJob.setSrc_server_pswd(drive.getPswd());

                        } else {
                            if ("OBJSTORAGE".equals(drive.getType())) {
                                newTransferJob.setDst_server_type("OOSS");
                            } else {
                                newTransferJob.setDst_server_type("NAS");
                            }
                            newTransferJob.setDst_server(drive.getSrc_server());
                            newTransferJob.setDst_server_dflt_loc(drive.getSrc_Loc());
                            newTransferJob.setDst_server_id(drive.getUsr_id());
                            newTransferJob.setDst_server_pswd(drive.getPswd());
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                 jobSubmitVo.setClientName(runVO.getClientName());
                 jobSubmitVo.setSrcServer(runVO.getSrcLoc());
                 jobSubmitVo.setDstServer(runVO.getDstLoc());
                 jobSubmitVo.setSrcServerDesc(runVO.getSrcLocDesc());
                 jobSubmitVo.setDstServerDesc(runVO.getDstLocDesc());
                 jobSubmitVo.setFileName(runVO.getFileName());
                 jobSubmitVo.setSizeOfFile("32");
                 jobSubmitVo.setUsrName(runVO.getLstUpdtIdCd());
                 jobSubmitVo.setMetaTag(runVO.getMetaTag());
                 jobSubmitVo.setRententionPeriod(runVO.getRetentionPrdcurrent());
                 jobSubmitVo.setTask_Id(runVO.getTask_Id());

                 if (!isObjStorage) {

                       //CURLProcessor uploader = new CURLProcessor();
                        // Export the scripts first

                        util.exportFiles(newTransferJob.getSrc_server(), newTransferJob.getSrc_server_id(),newTransferJob.getSrc_server_pswd(),newTransferJob.getSrc_server_dflt_loc());
                        uploadtrasnfer(newTransferJob, runVO.getFileName(), jobSubmitVo);
                    } else {





                        util.exportFiles(newTransferJob.getDst_server(), newTransferJob.getDst_server_id(),newTransferJob.getDst_server_pswd(),newTransferJob.getDst_server_dflt_loc());
                        downloadTrasnfer(newTransferJob, runVO.getFileName(), jobSubmitVo);
                    }

                   try {

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            }
```

Comment: i guess you need to post related code here. It is difficult to understand what might be wrong without it.

Comment: Hard to know what the problem is without examples

Comment: If you really want an answer to that, you'll need to construct a [mcve], which will take you a long time, I'm sure, as you'll need to rewrite the code such that we won't need a database to run it and see your problem. But I can't see you getting a good answer without putting in that effort.

Answer (score 0):

Your run() method gets the list of pending items once, and tries to handle them.  However, once they are handled, it does not appear to go back to get more pending items.  You need to put getting the list and handling the items in a loop.

There may be some other issues too.

Answer (score 0):

If your app runs within an Application server then you need your code that picks your submitted tasks from DB to run as a scheduled task. Say you want it to run every x minutes/hours and each time your code wakes up it reads all submitted tasks from DB until it finishes. The best way to do it is to use an external scheduler for example [quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/). Such scheduler can handle running your tasks periodically and can even handle it if your app runs in the cluster of servers. I.e. Quartz will ensure that no matter how many servers you have in cluster your task will run on only one of them exactly as you schedule it. If this is too much for you, then you still don't need to write your own Thread, which is an old way. Look at java class [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) and read about all different implementations. In particular see [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html) and [ScheduledExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html). Those should do what you need with much less coding